# Client side javascript table structure bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad practice to create objects matching server side table structures on the client side?  Are there any security concerns?

This would be used for creating new records and storing in an array on the client before saving to server.  Additionally used to retrieve records and store from the server.

For example:

```
    var recordClass = {
       fields: {
           col1: { dataType: "int", identity: true },
           col2: { dataType: "char", length:50 }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Downvote with no comment?  Just asking a question

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking; this question is pretty broad and will likely result in opinion-based answers, both of which are subject to being closed.

Comment: same experience my friend, old member not so friendly... vote down 4 times, leave a comment ask me to show code, then leave without answer... and they don't vote up again after I give my code, and for your question, what are you trying to do? do you want to save variable as string array.?

Comment: In short could a hacker use this column information for mischeif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad but I'll still give you my answer.  Some programmers will say it's dangerous to publicly distribute anything related to your database.  That would include structure, user names, error message.

Personally, I think you should put things in perspective.  If an hacker have access to your database structure, it would be easier for him to understand how to deal with the data available in your database. **However**, the database structure itself isn't enough to give him access to your data.  If you have secured your passwords and you have managed to prevent any risk of sql injection and every other flaws that could allow unwanted script to be executed on your DB, then using your structure in a public business layer should be safe.  I would also recommend preventing error messages from being sent back directly to the browser as it may provide a lot of informations an exploit could be created for your database.

P.S. Many data services are already using table names and structure without alias.  The service definition is sometime publicly available.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I find this method makes it a lot easier to create reusable javascript components.  I was thinking.  Would it make sense to create these objects from an httpRequest?  That information would still be visible in the responseBody though.  Any thoughts @The_Black_Smurf?

Comment: From the security point of view, making the structure available from a javascript file or from an httpRequest is the same.  Creating your object from an httpRequest does make sense as it's more dynamic.  However, you'll have to make sure your javascript is still able to deal with your objects if your change the structure.